# Reloading of javascript function via JQuery .change adds variables from previous runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I would like to change fonts dynamically, But my code only behaves nicely the first time i change a font. It seems that my code remembers previous clicked buttons and adds those to be changed as well every time i select a new font for a button. My code is available at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccwn52ts/2/)

```js
function font(id,element){
  $(id).bind('change',function(){
    var fontTypeSelected = $(id).val();
    $(element).css('font-family',fontTypeSelected);
  });
}

$('#settings-ID').change(function(){
  font('#font','#' + $('#settings-ID').val());
});
         
$('.list').on('click','.settings',function(){
  // Set current row or box section ID
  $('#settings-ID').val($(this).attr('id'));
  $("#settings-ID").trigger("change");
});
```

```css
.list div {
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:#CCC;
  margin:10px 10px 0 0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click on one of the buttons below to change font
<div class="list">
  <div class="settings" id="1">Font one</div>
  <div class="settings" id="2">Font two</div>
</div>
<br>Selected button ID: <input type="text" id="settings-ID" placeholder="None selected"><br>
<br>
<select class="form-control" id="font">
  <option>Arial</option>
  <option>Courier</option>
  <option>Verdana</option>
  <option>Times new roman</option>
</select>
```

I really hope someone can help me with this problem. I'm kind of stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining multiple change events when you call the function

Use `.unbind("change")` to delete the change event before defining the next one.

```
function font(id,element){
  $(id).unbind('change').bind('change',function(){
    var fontTypeSelected = $(id).val();
    $(element).css('font-family',fontTypeSelected);
  });
}
```